# How do I update the variable totalCost in the second class

Tags: java, class, object, methods

The program prompts the user for the number of hamburgers, salads, french, fries, and sodas and then displays the total for the order. The application should include a Food object with a constructor that accepts the price, fat, carbs, and fiber for an item. Food methods
should return the price of the item and return the fat, carbohydrates, and fiber. The line printed should be the total cost but it keeps printing that the total cost is $0. The problem is the variable that accumulates the cost is not updated in the second class.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class LunchOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double totalCost = 0;
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        System.out.print("Enter number of hamburgers: ");
        double hamburgerTotal = input.nextInt();
        Food foodOne = new Food("Hamburger", 1.85, 9.0, 33, 1, hamburgerTotal);
        System.out.println(foodOne + "\n");
        totalCost += hamburgerTotal * 1.85;    
        totalCost += foodOne.getTotalCost(); 

        System.out.print("Enter number of salads: ");
        double saladTotal = input.nextInt();
        Food foodTwo = new Food("Salad", 2.00, 1, 11, 5, saladTotal);
        System.out.println(foodTwo + "\n");
        totalCost += saladTotal * 2.00; 
        totalCost += foodTwo.getTotalCost();

        System.out.print("Enter number of french fries: ");
        double frenchFrieTotal = input.nextInt();
        Food foodThree = new Food("French fries", 1.30, 11, 36, 4, frenchFrieTotal);
        System.out.println(foodThree + "\n");
        totalCost += frenchFrieTotal * 1.30;       
        totalCost += foodThree.getTotalCost();

        System.out.print("Enter number of sodas: ");
        double sodaTotal = input.nextInt();
        Food foodFour = new Food("Soda", 0.95, 0, 38, 0, sodaTotal);
        System.out.println(foodFour + "\n"); 
        totalCost += sodaTotal * 0.95;  
        totalCost += foodFour.getTotalCost();

        System.out.println(foodFour.setPrice());
    }
}

class Food {
    String item;
    double price;
    double fat;
    double carb;
    double fiber;
    double total;
    double foodTotal;
    double totalCost;
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public  Food (String nItem, double nPrice, double nFat, double nCarb, double nFiber, double hamburgerTotal) {
        item = nItem;
        price = nPrice;
        fat = nFat;
        carb = nCarb;
        fiber = nFiber;
        foodTotal = hamburgerTotal;
        totalCost = totalCost +(price * foodTotal);
    }

    public void total() {
        double totalCost = price * foodTotal;
        totalCost += (price * foodTotal);
        System.out.println(money.format(totalCost));
        }

    public double getTotalCost(){ 
        return totalCost; 
    }

    public String setPrice() {
        String priceString; 

        priceString = "Your order comes to: " + totalCost;
        return(priceString);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String orderString;

        orderString =  "Each " + item + " has " + fat + "g of fat, "
                + carb + "g of carbs, and " + fiber + ".g of fiber.";
        return(orderString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The double variable " totalCost " is declared in both the classes LunchOrder and Food.

So updated totalCost value at last should be sent to `setPrice()` in Food class.

Also the totalCost variable used in `setPrice()` is the Food class variable and the one to be printed is the LunchOrder variable.

Updated code in LunchOrder class

```
  System.out.println(foodFour.setPrice(totalCost));
```

Updated setPrice()

```
public String setPrice(double total) {
    String priceString;
    this.total=total;
    priceString = "Your order comes to: " + total;
    return(priceString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need totalCost in a second class because a Food object is a single entity, not holding onto a running total of all created objects

That being said, this approach seems correct

```
     double totalCost = 0;

    Food hamburger = new Food(1.85, 9.0, 33, 1);
    totalCost += hamburger.getPrice() * hamburgerTotal;

    // get more food 

    System.out.print(totalCost);
```

Where the total cost would be defined as the number of items times the price

And the constructor doesn't need any total values, because that wasn't included in the description

> Food object with a constructor that accepts the price, fat, carbs, and fiber for an item

```
public  Food (double nPrice, double nFat, double nCarb, double nFiber) {
    price = nPrice;
    fat = nFat;
    carb = nCarb;
    fiber = nFiber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If You just want to print total price the you don't need call setPrice() method

Instead of call setPrice() method

```
System.out.println(foodFour.setPrice());
```

you can directly print

```
System.out.println(Your order comes to: " + totalCost);
```